# Optimizing a React App for Google Page Speed

Tags: reactjs, performance

I'm trying to improve the page speed (and SEO) performance of my React app at https://bravos.co. You can see the results of the page speed test here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=bravos.co

I'm stuck at 64/100 on mobile and 46/100 on desktop.

I've improved a number of things, but there's a lot that I'm just stuck on, and seems to be difficult to improve give it is a React app:

- Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold
  content **(this is mainly the bundle.js, which I can't eliminate given that it's the whole app)**
- Optimize CSS Delivery **(This is relatively minor, but I'm still not sure how to do it in React)**
- Enable compression (I can gzip some things here, still looking for an easy way to gzip and deploy a random javascript file)
- Leverage browser caching **(this I can't figure out how to do in React, particularly since .htaccess doesn't seem to be used)**

Any advice or thoughts here would be massively appreciated.

Comment: how are you serving your react application? are you using server side rendering at all?  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: No, not at all. In looking at the site - https://bravos.co - do you see major opportunities for server-side rendering? Many thanks.

Comment: I mean... every single one of those scores will increase if you serve the static page instead of serving a blank page and load javascript after